# How to make JUnit RunListener to save obtained data on every failure?

Tags: java, junit4

I'm obtaining the xml file by httpconnetion in my test and have to make a lot of checks. How can I get internal test data and serialize it when failure occures? Tried to use RunListener, but Failure class do not provide access to obtained data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested: I've created a Rule, wich intialized by received xml data and overrided failed() method